# Lock AD account c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

i need to lock AD account by c#. here is my function

```
/// <summary>
/// This Methoid will Disable the User Account based on the Directory Entry Object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="oDE">The Directoy Entry Object of the Account to Disable</param>
public void LockAccount(DirectoryEntry oDE)
{
   oDE.InvokeSet("IsAccountLocked", true); 
   //oDE.Properties["userAccountControl"][0] = ADMethods.ADAccountOptions.UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT | ADMethods.ADAccountOptions.UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD | ADMethods.ADAccountOptions.UF_ACCOUNT_LOCKOUT;
   //oDE.CommitChanges();
   //oDE.Close();
}
```

Run it and prom exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80005008    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.InvokeSet(String propertyName,
>   Object[] args)

Comment: Try setting it to false and see what happens? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746533(v=vs.85).aspx "Attempting to set the IsAccountLocked property to TRUE will fail. Only the system can lock an account."

Comment: this mean dont have any way to lock account programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the error comes up on the single uncommented line?

Is it possible that you do not have permission to lock a user.  What account permission are you running under?

[MSDN says InvokeSet should not be used](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.invokeset(v=vs.110).aspx)

[This CodeProject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C) goes into great detail with Active Directory, the specific code to disable an account is this:

```
public void Disable(string userDn)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry(userDn);
        int val = (int)user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
        user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val | 0x2; 
             //ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE;

        user.CommitChanges();
        user.Close();
    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
    {
        //DoSomethingWith --> E.Message.ToString();    
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using system admin permission. I can remote to AD machine and lock this account manually. Your code is disable user, i need method to lock AD user

Comment: There's very little difference between locking and disabling, http://www.windows-active-directory.com/difference-between-disabled-expired-and-locked-account.html  The only thing is that locked can be set to unlock after a predefined time limit whereas disabled stay that way.

Comment: The original CodeProject link had some code to lock accounts which was very much like your code, but I've read that it might not work (I can't test from where I am - no permissions).  An alternative method may be to lock by repeated programmatic false logon attempts, see https://sanjivblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/how-to-lock-the-ad-active-directory-account-programmatically-in-c/